# Wildcard doesn't work in ansible shell command

Tags: powershell, ansible

The shell command doesn't expand wildcard when running ansible module through powershell.

If I remove the wildcard and specify the version number it works 'rabbitmq_server-3.9.3'.

Any suggestion on how to make this work with wildcard?

Yaml code:

```
  - name: Check if RabbitMQ is already installed
    shell: "\"/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/RabbitMQ\ Server/rabbitmq_server-*/sbin/rabbitmq-service.bat\" status"
    ignore_errors: true
    register: RabbitMQ_install_status
```

Error:

'C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c ansible-playbook test.yml':

```
TASK [Check if RabbitMQ is already installed] **************************************************************************fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "\"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/RabbitMQ Server/rabbitmq_server-*/sbin/rabbitmq-service.bat\" status", "delta": "0:00:00.042184", "end": "2021-08-16 13:43:52.066236", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-08-16 13:43:52.024052", "stderr": "/bin/sh: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/RabbitMQ Server/rabbitmq_server-*/sbin/rabbitmq-service.bat: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/RabbitMQ Server/rabbitmq_server-*/sbin/rabbitmq-service.bat: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring
```

Comment: The `shell` module is for Unix systems. With PowerShell and Windows you need to use `win_shell`.

Answer (score 0):

The shell doesn't expand the wildcard because you have put it in quotes. Wildcard expansion is not done in either single or double quotes.

```
\"/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/RabbitMQ\ Server/rabbitmq_server-*/sbin/rabbitmq-service.bat\"
```

Presumably you have done this to escape the spaces in the path.

Try quoting only the part of the path that needs to be quoted.

```
\"/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/RabbitMQ\ Server\"/rabbitmq_server-*/sbin/rabbitmq-service.bat
##                                           ##
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `.*`

"/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/RabbitMQ\ Server/rabbitmq_server-.*/sbin/rabbitmq-service.bat"